# My university says they have no record of my diploma from 25 years ago. What can I do for my background check?

Tags: background-check

I got a diploma from University in UK over 25 years ago, background check called the university and the university has no record as it was paper back then.  What can i do?  My parents no-longer have my diploma certificate.
Can i ever get a job without this now?

Comment: 25 years ago was the mid-late 90's, not the stone age. Electronic records and tape backups were available. Call BS and tell them to get your records. Unless you went to a fake University that didn't issue you an actual diploma.

Comment: @dfundako You'd be surprised at the systems some places are still using to this day.

Comment: @Dukeling Absolutely. But if you found out that your alma mater could not produce documentation for any student that graduated pre 1995, you could have a lot of fun with that.

Comment: Did the background agency contact the correct university? When I was consultant, one of the background agencies my client used tried to get my info from a university in India - despite the fact I obtained my degree in Scotland and have never set foot in India.

Comment: I graduated in 1985 and a phone call to my university (in the US) will claim the same.  But using a written form to request proof will still work.

Comment: Did this background check occur as part of an interview process or something else?

Comment: It is hard for me to believe a university does not have records.  That would severely hurt their reputation.

Comment: Does the University have no records at all of people who graduated 25 years ago (highly unlikely) or do they just have no record of you ?

Comment: What is your field of work?

Comment: @Hilmar that's the most pertinent question - if it's the case that they only don't have the records for OP (but do keep records in general) it could be a mistake, a name mispelled or the wrong birthday used etc. Narrowing this down may help the university to correctly identify OP and locate their records.

Comment: I think it is more likely that they couldn't answer the question within the duration of a phone call, as they would first need to request it from a paper archive (possibly off-site) instead of looking it up on their computer. Likely the person answering the call didn't want to be bothered doing that or the vetting company wanted an immediate answer and not wait for the result from the archive. I'd suggest you contact your university yourself.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I ever get a job without this now?

It depends on the type of job you are willing to apply to. You can work on software development without ever going to school. However, nobody will think of employing a doctor with no university degree.

Regarding the certificate, I am sure the university that issued you the certificate 25 years ago will be able to provide a copy or proof of that previous education. There is no doubt they are keeping records from 25 years ago. For a country like the UK, it is highly likely the university was using computerised record-keeping systems.

Comment: I bet a uk uni could provide records from the day it opened, if it could be arsed, that last phrase is the important one.